# Consulta de multiples sumas en MYSQL

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla con un sistema de referidos y totales, intento hacer un join con la tabla usuarios, pero no sé cómo evitar errores en la suma, me explico con las tablas:

Compras:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero sacar algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De tal manera que se sume todo lo que tienen un usuario en el nivel 1, hago un left join y me funciona con un unico nivel, al hacerlo de nuevo por los niveles adicionales me salen valores erroneos,

a continuación el código que estoy utilizando:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW levels AS
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, 
users.username,
SUM( t1.tl1) as level1, 
SUM( t2.tl2) as level2, 
SUM( t3.tl3) as level3
FROM users
LEFT JOIN refer AS t1 ON t1.l1 = users.id
LEFT JOIN refer AS t2 ON t2.l2 = users.id
LEFT JOIN refer AS t3 ON t3.l3 = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que queres hacer... si queres solo una columna, porque traes 3?

Comment: Lo que pretendo es generar las otras consultas, con una sola, me funciona, pero no he podido hacer para que me sume correctamente las adicionales. 

gracias

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación.

Answer (score 0):

Tu dificultad parece estar relacionada con los valores `NULL` de los campos en tu sumas, pues es un valor que se repite mucho y, con que un único `id` sea nulo, lleva toda la suma de ese `id` a `NULL`:

```
SUM( t1.tl1) as level1,
```

Prueba aplicando la función `IFNULL()` en todos los campos:

```
SUM( IFNULL(t1.tl1,0) ) as level1,
```